# How can I submit a form_tag to update the current page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to coding and Rails. I and have worked through the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, but I am still very raw. I am hoping someone can explain this to me or point me to a resource. My Google skills were failing me.

When a user lands on my homepage I am generating a random password for them. But if they want to generate a new password I'd like to provide them with some options. I started with capitalizing a random letter.

```
<%= form_tag(root_path, method: 'get') do %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:random_capital) %>
  <%= label_tag(:random_capital, "Capitalize a random letter") %>
<%= submit_tag("Generate a new password") %>
<% end %>
```

I have the above form on my homepage and when I tick the checkbox I do manage to get a value of 1 passed through an instance variable and can display that value back to my homepage along with a new password

But this code in my controller action is never triggering

```
  if @randomness == 1
    random_capital words
  end
```

So I get a new password when I submit the form, but not with a random capital.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was in the following code

```
if @randomness == 1
```

I did not realize the value of params[:random_capital] was a string, not an integer.

```
if @randomness == '1'
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `params[:random_capital]`, not `@randomness`. I would also advise to move this logic to a separate controller.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the separate controller. I have Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby on my list of books to tackle so hopefully I can gain some more direction there. Any other recommendations are also appreciated!